# How to check if a given email is present in firebase auth?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, reset-password

I want to implement a reset password form. For that I need to check whether the text input email that user **input** in out text field is present in our firebase authentication database or not, so that if it is I can send Reset password mail or else show him a pop-dialog to rectify the email.

I've already applied the email checking part where I check wether the text is **Email** or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase Auth can actually manage that for you. Simply call the `sendPasswordResetEmail()` method like this:

```dart
_auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: email)
        .then((void v) => {
          // password reset email sent successfully
        })
        .catchError((Error error) => {
          // There was an error verifying the email
          // Check the output of error.toString()
          // This is where you may want to show a pop-up dialog
        });
```

If the email is badly formatted or if the email is not present on the Auth Database, the code will always execute the `catchError` method.